# What's the point of using track-by attribute along with v-for?

Tags: vue.js

I'm a newbie at vuejs. It seems to me the track-by attribute is a little hard to understand. The following example shows the track-by attribute has something to do with the duplicate elements in an array.But how is the v-for attribute implemented under the hood? What's the behavior when there are duplicate elements in an array and how **track-by="$index"** comes to make a difference?

```js
new Vue({

 el: '#app',
  
  data: function() {
   return {
     items: [
       'User Connected',
        'Message',
        'Message',
        'User Connected',
        'Message'
      ]
    }
  },
  
  methods: {
   addItem: function(item) {
   this.items.push(item);
    }
  }

})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <button @click="addItem('User Connected')">Add Connected</button>
  <button @click="addItem('Message')">Add Message</button>

  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in items" track-by="$index">{{ item }}</li>
  </ul>
  <pre>
    {{items | json}}
  </pre>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uuw4z0kr/2/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to be reactive and fast, Vue re-uses DOM elements whenever possible.  So if it has already rendered the DOM for a particular item, it will save it to use anytime that needs to be rendered again.  If something is removed from the array, then added back in, it will be faster to use existing HTML.

But this causes issues when the array elements are not unique.  Vue can't distinguish them.  `track-by` tells Vue which aspect of each item is unique, so it can know when to re-use DOM elements.  If your array is a series of objects with an `id` attribute, you can use `track-by='id'`.  But if the objects don't have a unique field, `track-by='$index'` associates each object with its position in the array.  This is inherently a unique attribute, so it suppresses the error for duplicate entries.